How come EF Core is able to assign NULL to a non-nullable property?
NRT is enabled.
I have the following models:
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Header Header { get; set; }
}

public class Header
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

According to docs, EF Core respects NRT and will use it to set columns to be nullable or not if NRT is enabled, which it is.
Now, I know that having Header be non-nullable in a principal entity doesn't make sense, but EF Core is completely ignoring it. I can even create a Blog without any Header linked! A Header will be set to NULL if I create a blog without a header.
It's also frustrating, even though it makes sense, that the compiler thinks it can't be NULL yet it is!
The migration code is:
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Blogs",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    Url = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Blogs", x => x.Id);
                });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Headers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    BlogId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Headers", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Headers_Blogs_BlogId",
                        column: x => x.BlogId,
                        principalTable: "Blogs",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

How come EF Core is able to assign NULL to a non-nullable property?

What makes you think it is allowing #null? Everything you shows indicates it is setting up the schema to be non-null-able.  If your issue is that when you read a Blog the Header navigation property is #null, that is because you aren't eager loading reference data. NRT do not prevent reference types from being #null, it just adds an extra compiler check to warn you if code structure is leaving some unassigned or set to #null. EF won't let you save a new blog without a header or vice-versa due to constraints in the DB that code-first will set up in accordance to NRT.

As you say, Blog is the principal entity. Hence table Blog doesn't have a HeaderId, so the database allows Blogs without Headers. It even has no way to enforce Blogs to have Headers. EF core has always followed the line of making validation a developer-responsibility and I think that's why they allow the entity model to do what the database allows. They're not going to validate it for you. As for reading: you can configure Header as auto-include. If this answers your question I can convert it into an answer, if you like.

@StevePy, EF actually let me save a Blog without a Header! Also, if NRT is enabled and a navigation is required (non-nullable), EF will bring that entity without using .Include. In other words, if I add 2 blogs, one with a header and one without and query for all blogs, I will get both blogs with one of them having their linked header and one with header as null.

@GertArnold, even though what you said makes sense, I still do not understand how bringing back a blog from the DB without a header can materialize as a Blog while Header is non-nullable. Please note that if I try to access the Title in the header, I get an error. Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

@noobie If your schema has a non-nullable FK then EF cannot save a blog without a header. The database would not persist the row so it's possible the schema differs from what your migrations indicate. As for pulling back without include, EF will populate associations from tracked references even if you don't eager load. So in one case if the header had been previously loaded, pulling a blog that references it will have the reference populated. Another blog with a different header will come back without a header if you don't eager load.

Check the DB schema as I suspect that even though your entity classes are set to not allow null, the database has the FK null-able. If using code-first your migrations haven't been run or are somewhat out of sync. Simply enabling NRT does not FORCE C# or EF to  not allow #null in the reference, reference types can always be null. What it does is warn you if your code leaves one uninitialized, and EF's schema generation will respect NRTs to mark schema creation/edit scripts to set null-ability.

@StevePy, my migration code does not have any FK on Blog table. I think this is by design. Check out this (paragraph)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-one#:~:text=A%20required%20relationship,for%20more%20information.] in EF docs. If I want to enforce it, I'll have to use FluentAPI. What Gert said makes sense to me now. NRT is a compile-time check. During runtime, there's nothing preventing me from assigning null. This is what EF is doing. I just hoped that EF will show a warning regarding not respecting NRT for principal to dependent relation.

Note that NRT is nothing but a compiler feature that issues warnings at compile-time where code may throw a NRE. It doesn't change anything on actual nullability of reference types. I.e. Blog.Header can always be null. It's not a problem for C# with NRT enabled and EF chooses to not make it their problem.

Thank you, @GertArnold. I read more into the docs and indeed a relationship, if not using FluentAPI to enforce it, from a principal to a dependent must be nullable since its optional. And yes, NRT is only at compile-time. I didn't know that. I thought it's a guarantee.

Feel free to write all of this into an answer with links to docs if you'd like and I'll mark it as an answer. This is where I got the relations rules from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/navigations#required-navigations

As you say, Blog is the principal entity. Hence table Blog doesn't have a HeaderId, so the database allows Blogs without Headers. It even has no way to enforce Blogs to have Headers.
EF core has always followed the line of making validation a developer-responsibility and I think that's why they allow the entity model to do what the database allows. They're not going to validate it for you.
As for reading: you can configure Blog.Header as auto-include.
Even then, you can still get a null value in Blog.Header, note that NRT is nothing but a compiler feature that issues warnings at compile-time where code may throw a NRE. It doesn't change anything on actual nullability of reference types. I.e. Blog.Header can always be null. It's not a problem for C# with NRT enabled and EF chooses to not make it their problem.
